# Integration using parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I am struggling to evaluate this integral:
$$
\int e^{(\mu +r)t+\frac{r}{\alpha}\sin(\alpha t)}\cos(\alpha t)dt
$$
The integration just gets harder and harder when integrating by parts! Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which equation?

Comment: Make sure you're choosing the right parts. What's your $u$ and $dv$?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha cannot solve analytically even the greatly simplified case of $\mu=0,r=\alpha=1$. Is this an expression you arrived at on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write $$e^{(\mu+r)t+\frac r\alpha\sin(\alpha t)}\cos(\alpha t)=e^{(\mu+r)t}e^{\frac r\alpha\sin(\alpha t)}\cos(\alpha t)$$Notice that the last two terms have trigonometric functions with the argument $(\alpha t)$. This indicates there may be a connection between these two terms. What happens if you integrate $e^{\frac r\alpha\sin(\alpha t)}\cos(\alpha t)$?